# Errors trying to send email via Apex class

Tags: apex

I have a contact information section on a VF page. In this section, 'Email' is a field, and in another section I have a custom template. When I submit the page(via a Save button) I need to get the input of the 'Email' field and send an email with the custom template as the body.

Here is my code:

```
public void sendEmail(){ 
    Messaging.singleEmailMessage email1 = new Messaging.singleEmailMessage(); 
    String userEmail = new String(); 
    userEmail = Billing.Billingemail; 
    email1.setToAddresses(userEmail); 
    Messaging.sendEmailResult res = 
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.singleEmailMessage[] {email1}); 
    system.debug('resulttt'+res); 
}
```

Getting error

> Compile Error: Type cannot be constructed: String at line 771 column 27

Any ideas?

Note: I get the custom template through xml from another object.

Comment: The error is because you have:
String userEmail=new String();
You don't construct strings in that way, just instantiate it and you can assign to it:
String userEmail=Billing.Billingemail;

Comment: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Messaging.SingleEmailMessage].setToAddresses(String)  email1.setToAddresses(userEmail);

Comment: settoaddresses takes an array of strings - e.g.
email1.setToAddresses(new String[]{userEmail});

Comment: Can u give me an example  Bob...I'm fed up with this....My requirement is I need to pass value from Billing.billingemail into settoaddress...

Comment: You can reduce it down to:
email1.setToAddresses(new String[]{Billing.billingEmail});

Comment: @BobBuzzard - could you create an answer with your first and last comments? Seems like those fix it.

Comment: @metadaddy - I was just composing a question on meta to find out the guidelines for this!  I'd appreciate some guidance for the future so will still post that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't construct a string in that way - you can simply declare it and assign a value:

```
String userEmail=Billing.Billingemail;
```

however, you can reduce this further and simply pass the Billing.BillingEmail to the setToAddresses method of SingleEmailMessage as long as you wrap it up in an array:

```
email1.setToAddresses(new String[]{Billing.billingEmail});
```